# Relationship between two db entities

Tags: erd

[My relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCBTO.png)
I have a Place table and Tour table in DB. 
In Tour, I have a start-place and end-place.
I don't know what's exactly true realation between them. 
Thanks for watch!

Answer (score 0):

You have two relationships, represented by `(tour_id, start_place_id)` and `(tour_id, end_place_id)`. These are both many-to-one binary relationships, since each tour has a single start place and end place, while a place can be the starting point or ending point of multiple tours.